# Provision throughput on Database level using Table API in cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have come across the requirement where I have to choose the API for Cosmos DB.

I have gone through with all API's like SQL,Graph, Mongo and Table. Since my current project structure is based on Table storage where I am storing IoT Device data.

In Current structure (Table storage) :

I have a separate Table for each Device with payload like below
{ 
   Timestamp,
   Parameter name,
   value
}

Now If I plan to use Cosmos DB then I can see that I have to Provision RU/throughput against each table which I think going to be big cost. I have not found any way to assign RU on database level so that my allocated RU can be shared across all tables.

Please let me know in case we have something here.... or is it the limitation i can treat for CosmosDB with Table API?

As far as I can see SQL API and consider my use case I can create a single data base and then multiple collection (with the name of Table) and then I have both option for RU provision like on Database as well as on Device level which give me more control on cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the throughput on the account level.

> You can optionally provision throughput at the account level to be shared by all tables in this account, to reduce your bill. These settings can be changed ONLY when you don't have any tables in the account. Note, throughput provisioned at the account level is billed for, whether you have tables created or not. The estimate below is approximate and does not include any discounts you may be entitled to.

[Azure Cosmos DB pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/)

> The throughput configured on the database is shared across all the containers of the database. You can choose to explicitly exclude certain containers from database provisioning and instead provision throughput for those containers at container level.
>
> A Cosmos DB database maps to the following: a database while using SQL or MongoDB APIs, a keyspace while using Cassandra API or a database account while using Gremlin or Table storage APIs.

[image: Azure Portal Setting]

Answer (score 0):

You can embed [Cerebrata](https://cerebrata.com/) into the situation where the tools allow you to assign any number of throughput values post assigning the throughput type (fixed, auto-scale, or no throughput)

Disclaimer: It’s purely based on my experience